# BigBlueButton internal audio controls

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am trying to integrate BBB with existing ui elements. I could find the basic api list on the website but am unable to find other internal requests, like how does the mute/unmute functionality works etc. Is there a way I could find the list of internal API's?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the bigbluebutton's codes in GitHub, I think you can find all of their internal APIs list in this directory:

```
bigbluebutton-html5/imports/api/
```

and html5 codes related to audio are located in places like:

```
bigbluebutton-html5/imports/ui/components/audio
bigbluebutton-html5/imports/api/audio
bigbluebutton-html5/imports/api/voice-users
...
```